# Chrome not returning cookies to server

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask

I'm using Flask, and I'm setting a session cookie. Here are the headers where my cookie is being set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Length: 168
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 15:02:04 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
Set-Cookie: session=.eJx9(lots of bits cut); HttpOnly; Path=/
Vary: Origin, Cookie
```

But subsequent requests aren't sending the cookie back to the client. What's going on?